# Keep a delay Or Pausing in Jquery array after reading each element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following program which reads elements from an array and does some processing .

After reading each element , i want to keep a delay of 3 seconds .

This is my complete program

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>
    </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var symbols = [ "AAA","BBB"];

      $(document).ready(function () {

        $.each( symbols, function( index, value ){
          loadXMLDoc(value);
        });

        doPoll();

      }
                       );
      function loadXMLDoc(value)
      {
        alert('onready'+value);
      }


      function doPoll(){
         $.each( symbols, function( index, value ){
            poll(value);
         });
        setTimeout(doPoll,4000);
      }


      function poll(value)
      {
          alert('poll'+value);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

I want to keep a delay of 3 seconds at these points

here

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $.each( symbols, function( index, value ){
          loadXMLDoc(value);
        });
        doPoll();
      }
  );
```

and at here

```
function doPoll(){

   $.each( symbols, function( index, value ){
     poll(value);
   });
   setTimeout(doPoll,4000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

See jQuery documentation .delay();

Answer (score 0):

you can try this out-

```
$.each( symbols, function( index, value ){
      setInterVal(function() {
          loadXMLDoc(value);
      }, 500);
    });
```

time in miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each( symbols, function( index, value ){
setTimeout( function () {
   loadXMLDoc(value);
}, index* 3000);//run the code after 3 second
});
```